# Dependency from local feed can't be resolved

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, nuget

I created a nuget package and made it available locally via a [local feed](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds). In Visual Studio 2015 I am able to install this package via Nuget after I added the feed to my package sources. Unfortunately, I get the following error in my ASP.Net Core project when I install the package:

> Code NU1001
>   The dependency [my package] could not be resolved.

Any hints what I can do to make it work? I am using VS 2015 Update 3 and Tooling Preview 2. The project is a empty ASP.NET Core Web Application referencing the full .NET Framework.

Comment: Do you mean that just the Core apps have this issue? How about other project? How about removing some dependencies from your package to narrow down this issue? http://forums.asp.net/t/2080135.aspx?Referencing+regular+NET+Class+Library+in+ASP+NET+5+project

Comment: Does it occur with other project types? For example Console Application project.